# Nested select menu in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

How do we create or is it possible to create a nested select menu like the example select screenshot menu below but using my mat-select below , if user select an item from REPM mat select it will show on the right side the Master Broker Company menu. Thanks.

#example select

[image]

#html code

```
<div style="margin-top: 8px;margin-left:8px;">  
                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="transaction-control-filter">
                                    <mat-label class="transaction-detail-header-label">REPM</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select #rempselect multiple (openedChange)="changeREMPFilter($event)">
                                        <div  class="select-all-property-transaction-list">
                                            <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="allSelectedREMP" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                                (change)="toggleAllSelectionREMP()">Select All</mat-checkbox>
                                        </div>
                                        <mat-option (click)="optionClickREMP()" *ngFor="let remp of repmList" [value]="remp.display">
                                            {{remp.display}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select> 
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>

                            <div style="margin-top: 8px;margin-left:8px;">  
                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="transaction-control-filter">
                                    <mat-label class="transaction-detail-header-label">Master Broker Company</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select #companyselect multiple (openedChange)="changeCompanyFilter($event)">
                                        <div class="select-all-property-transaction-list">
                                            <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="allSelectedMasterBrokerCompany" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                                (change)="toggleAllSelectionCompany()">Select All</mat-checkbox>
                                        </div>
                                        <mat-option (click)="optionClickMasterBroker()" *ngFor="let masterbroker of transactionMasterBrokerCompany" [value]="masterbroker.display">
                                            {{masterbroker.display}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select> 
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
```

#this is my existing mat select

[image]

Comment: No , there is no such functionality in mat-select, you need to use mat-menu

Comment: is it possible to duplicate my REMP menu with checkboxes using mat-menu?

Comment: yes you can have checkboxes in your menu, but the handling of clicks is up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you would like to look into `mat-menu` with checkboxes. User will select (by checking) an item from REPM. Which will call a function, that updates possible selection in Master Broker Company? For example, in my demo, you can only select items from Master that correspond to items in REPM. I mocked some data using card / users to illustrate the point.

```html
<button #matMenuTrigger mat-raised-button color="primary"[matMenuTriggerFor]="repm" 
(menuOpened)="onMenuOpened()"
(menuClosed)="onMenuClosed()">REPM</button>
‎‎‎      ‎ ‎‎‎ ‎‎ 
<button #matMenuTrigger mat-raised-button color="primary"[matMenuTriggerFor]="master" 
(menuOpened)="onMenuOpened()"
(menuClosed)="onMenuClosed()">Master Broker Company</button>

<mat-menu #repm="matMenu">
  <mat-checkbox #menuItems
    *ngFor="let item of premiumAutomobilesList; let i = index;"
    [(ngModel)]="item.activated"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    (change)="onVehicleSelect()"
    (keydown)="onMenuKeyDown($event, i)"
    >{{ item.title }}</mat-checkbox
  >
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #master="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of users; let i = index;">
  <mat-checkbox #menuItems *ngIf="selectedVehicles.includes(item.car) "
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    (change)="onSelectUsername(item)"
    >{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox
  >
</ng-container>
</mat-menu>

<p>{{ formattedSelectedVehicles }}</p>
```

```js
  public onVehicleSelect() {
    this.selectedVehicles = this.premiumAutomobilesList
      .filter(menuitem => menuitem.activated)
      .map(menuitem => menuitem.title);
      console.log(this.selectedVehicles)
  }

  onSelectUsername(item: any) {
    console.log(item)
  }
```

Here is an example of mat-menu with checkboxes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/matmenu-with-checkboxes-demo-ohada6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmatmenu-with-checkboxes.ts

Comment: "User will select (by checking) an item from REPM. Which will call a function, that updates possible selection in Master Broker Company?" Yes , that is correct

Comment: do you have an example with this scenarion "User will select (by checking) an item from REPM. Which will call a function, that updates possible selection in Master Broker Company?"

Comment: If I check or select an Item from REPM how will the Master Broker Company menu show on the right side?

Comment: Sure. I have updated my demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/matmenu-with-checkboxes-demo-ohada6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmatmenu-with-checkboxes.ts

Comment: Sir how do we make it that I no longer need to show a Master Broker Button like in your example , it should be like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZbi1.png

Comment: I wanted to make it the same as  i.stack.imgur.com/oZbi1.png , where there will be no longer Master Broker Company Button, once I check an item on REMP the Master Broker Company menu will automatically show on the right side the same on that imgur example. Sir

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GupNqOB , It should look like this Sir , when I check a box from REPM the company broker name menu will show on the right side